# DB2 cast partial blob to varchar

Tags: sql, casting, db2, blob, varchar

I have a **db2** table with a **blob** column which contains **gzipped xml data**. Now I'd like to get approximately 20 characters from the beginning of the xml. I tried to **cast** the **blob to** a **varchar**, which works fine as long as the whole blob can be cast to a varchar. If it is **too long**, then i will get an error and the sql request breaks with following error: *SQL Error [22001]: Value "..." is too long.. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.14.88*

Is there any chance to **cast only** the **first part of the blob?**

What i'd like to achieve is, to get an id from the xml, which than can be used as a part of another sql request.

My sql so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(DATA AS VARCHAR(17)),10,8,OCTETS)
FROM table
WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = '123';
```

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't DB2 support SUBSTRING (or a similar function) on Blobs/Binary Data? If the column is gzipped, then how can you get the first n characters without unzipping?

Comment: In fact you are absolutely right! :)  I did not noticed that it is that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [dnoeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527905/dnoeth) said in his comment, the answer is simply to substr the blob itself before casting it.
So the sql looks like this:
`SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(DATA,10,8) AS VARCHAR(8))
FROM table
WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = '123';`